# how to show text from a website in netbeans output using java

Tags: java, html, netbeans

http://mahathirtanmoy.wix.com/tanmoy-world
It is a randomly generated website which used WIX editor where just i added two sentences

Hello word

OK JOB DONE.​

i want to show this two sentences using java programming on netbeans IDE output.
Plz advice me what should i study for this and what is the process i have to follow.
If i know how to do this ,later i can be able to share code if there comes any further difficulty.Can i do that for any HTML page?

Comment: So do you want to access HTML and parse it's content and display body part (or some specific) part on console?

Comment: Yes right that,what should i do?

Comment: So, david99world has given right solution for same. You should use jsoup for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have used it for read my IP address from http://www.whatismyip.org and it worked fine.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
public class ReadIp{

        public void getIP() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
             String ip="";
             String nextLine;
           URL url = null;
           URLConnection urlConn = null;
           InputStreamReader  inStream = null;
           BufferedReader buff = null;


              url  = new URL("http://www.whatismyip.org" );
              urlConn = url.openConnection();
             inStream = new InputStreamReader( 
              urlConn.getInputStream());
               buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);


                while ((nextLine =buff.readLine()) !=null){
            System.out.println(nextLine); 
        }

                  }
}
```

Comment: Mr. Prabhakar what should i import  here?

Comment: oh sorry net connection was cut and i could copy half

Comment: But should not use main method in any senese?

Comment: I am trying to use your code in net beans but i dont know what to write for this in  public static void main .I am new in java pls bro tell me what to do?

Comment: ok it worked ,thanks for code here i atlast i did rest of the thing

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the web site and return the two sentences.

Comment: how can i use that Jsoup staff in netbeans?

Comment: Yeah of course, it's just a jar file to include in the buildpath.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReadIp{
    public int getIP() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
             try
             {
            String ip = "";
            String nextLine;
            URL url = null;
            URLConnection urlConn = null;
            InputStreamReader inStream = null;
            BufferedReader buff = null;


            url = new URL("http://mahathirtanmoy.wix.com/tanmoy-world");
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            inStream = new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConn.getInputStream());
            buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);


            while ((nextLine = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(nextLine);
            }}
             catch(Exception ex)
             {}
            return 0;

        }

         public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            ReadIp rp = new ReadIp();
            rp.getIP();
        }
    }
}
```